# Can any ERC20 initial supply have 0?

Tags: token, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, erc20

I am creating an ERC20 token. Can I make initial supply 0? If yes than how will increase supply later on?

I just wanna know that can I make initial supply 0 while deploying an ERC20 token?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create an ERC20 token with 0 initial supply by not minting any tokens in the constructor.

Example code with the [OpenZeppelin ERC20](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/erc20) implementation. Mind that this code is simplified and not suitable for production as it allows minting new tokens by anyone.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20 {
  constructor(string memory name, string memory symbol) ERC20(name, symbol) {
    // no token minting in constructor => initial supply is 0
  }

  // you can call this function later to increase the total supply
  function mint(uint256 amount) external {
    _mint(msg.sender, amount);
  }
}
```